# 2007 MX-5 - Motor will not turn fully after timing change replacement

Tags: mazda, timing, chain, miata

I recently replaced my timing chain, tensioners, guides, waterpump, etc. I felt like I followed the instructions properly. When I attempted to start the car once complete the engine would not turn over, it acts like the crank is seized.  I removed the sparkplugs and belt and now I can turn the crank all the way to where the No 1 piston is at the bottom, then the crank stops, I reverse and I can go all the way the other way and then it stops where the No 1 piston is at the bottom.  It's like the crackshaft alignment pin is still in place but is not.  Any suggestions would be grateful

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It surely sounds like the timing is off. I'd go back and double check everything by starting at the beginning. Don't assume *anything*.

Comment: Have you left a pin or something on the camshaft?

Comment: Also, if you moved the cams, then you could be running into an issue of the valves trying to open while a piston is all the way up... which won't work obviously. *I will say don't continue trying to force it!*

Comment: ^^^^ but if the valves are open why is it acting like the crank is siezed, wouldn’t it just push the air out?